# Getting feature names in addition to values - SciKitLearn+Pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I generate a set of features for input, that I store as a table using pandas and the CSV  format. 
(Each column header represents a feature names, except for the first, blank column, which is where the class labels are stored for each row).

My next step is reading the table from the csv file, into scikit learn. (I'm currently doing this with pandas again). However, after training and experimenting with my models using different feature selection methods (and different initially generated features), I want the NAMES of the selected features. 
I assume this should be trivial, but I just haven't found how to do it.
(Note: I am NOT working on standard text documents, so "CountVectorizer" and "NaiveBayes"/nltk and the like do not help me).
 I need a method to get the selected features, (and preferably something to drop the unselected ones, for when I apply the models and selected features on new "test" data).

Thank you very much!

My data is currently loaded like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, LabelBinarizer

def load_data(filename="Feat_normalized.csv") :
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)
    lb = LabelEncoder()
    labels = lb.fit_transform((df.index.values))
    features = df.values
    feature_names = list(df.columns)
    feature_names.pop(0)  #Remove index.
    return (features, labels, lb)

features, labels, lb_encoder = load_data(filename)
X, y = features, labels

clf_logit = LogisticRegression(penalty="l1", dual=False, class_weight='auto')
X_reduced = clf_logit.fit_transform(X, y)
print('New sparse (filtered) features matrix size:')
print(X_svm.shape)

#Then fit to various models, Random forests, SVM, etc'..
```

Truncated Example of the first 2 rows in the input data/csv:

```
            AA_C    AA__D   AA__E   AA_F    AA__G   AA_H    AA_I    AA_K    AA_L    AA_M
Mammal_sequence_1.0.fasta   3.838099345 0.456591162 3.764884604 3.620232638 3.460992571 3.858487012 2.69247235  3.18710619  3.671029774 4.625996297 1.542632799
```

(AA_"" = Feature name. Mammal_sequence_1.0.fasta = Class name/label; (1 per row, empty header).

Thank you very much!